# What is the full flow of the Microsoft's authentication via the browser?

Tags: windows, azure, authentication

Windows desktop tools like *Azure Storage Expoler* and *Azure CLI* support using a browser to authenticate. For example, for Azure ClI the sequence is:

1. `az login`

   [image]
2. Web Browser launches

   [image]
3. The request is redirected to an localhost address

   [image]
4. SUCCESS

## Flow

I imagine the process to be something like the following:

1. Login option is run in an application like Azure CLI's `az login`, Azure Storage Explorer etc.
2. The application starts a http server on a ~random port.
3. The application opens the default browser at
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?

   1. client_id=...
   2. &response_type=code
   3. &redirect_uri=http://localhost:56094  <--- !
   4. &...
4. After authenticating successfully the browser makes a http request to the *redirect_uri* with a code
5. The application uses the code **`<here my understanding ends>`**

   1. ...with some extra information that cannot be sniffed over the localhost list...
   2. ...to obtain access and refresh tokens
   3. ...or the code is used directly as access token

## Question(s)

How is the code from the localhost request used and how is the flow protected from sniffing the localhost traffic (AFAIK while localhost cannot be redirected it can be recorded)?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess.

localhost can't be over https because there shouldn't be a certificate for that address.  So if using you really want to make sure secrets aren't passed

The localhost port is allocated and binded to first. That is, the socket listening on port 64656 in your picture is created, binded to and sets the [SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/so-exclusiveaddruse) flag via setsockopt.  That should do a reasonable job of preventing other bad guy processes from trying to get in on the same port.

Then the URL it forms with http://localhost:port can be formed knowing that the browser process, when it hits that URL, will hit the socket established in the last step.

Further, I would also hope that all the HTTP and HTTPS sessions in the flow have the `no cache` flag or equivalent flags to tell the browser to not record these URLs in the history.  I suppose you could press F12 on that browser window and observe.

I would also hope that the redirect URL has an attribute containing a nonce or random number that the localhost server is expecting. That way, it can get some validation that the redirect came from the same browser session as the control.

Secure?  Mostly. You don't have to worry about anything external trying to eavesdrop on the data being passed on those URLs.  Hypothetically, malware could get on the box and sniff your localhost traffic or simply monitor your keystrokes.  But if that's the case, it's already game over.

In our product code, we host oauth dialogs using embedded browser controls such as the WebView2 or legacy Trident controls. Those browser controls allow the host EXE to listen for navigation events and monitor the URL that would appear in the address bar (had we opted to show it). We can simply have the redirect be a bogus URL and just close the window when we see the redirect being passed the secret.